# Using Go to create office 365 outlook mailboxes

Tags: go, office365, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I am currently writing a rest API in Go and one of the features is to create office 365 mailboxes. Powershell has the command New-Mailbox, does anyone know if there is a package for Go that "talks" to office 365 exchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) REST APIs. Namely [CreateUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) request.

There is also [go-msgraph](https://github.com/open-networks/go-msgraph) package wrapping Microsoft Graph API's in Golang.

Comment: Oh thats a good idea! Thanks for letting me know so quickly!

However i notice a bearer token is required and we have an exchange server locally, ill have a talk with someone at work and ill find out, thanks anyways.

Comment: Graph supports hybrid environments too (in preview at least): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/hybrid-rest-support